# How to show a function is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I'm working on some problems involving limits. I need to show that if $ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 $ such that $x_0 - \delta < x_1, x_2 < x_0 \implies |f(x_1) - f(x_2) | < \epsilon$, then  $\lim_{x \to x_0^-} f(x) $ exists and is finite.

using some properties of the left limit superior $  = \beta $ and the left limit inferior $ = \alpha $,  I am able to show that $\alpha = \beta $, which will prove that the limit exists and is finite. However, to do this I first need to show that $ f$ is bounded on some interval $ [a, x_0) $. This is where I am stumped. My best guess would be to set $ M = Max \{f(x) : x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0)\} $. However, this obviously does not work as $ f$ need not have a maximum. My main problem is I don't know where to begin, and I'm not sure if I should be trying to find a value of $a$ in terms of $x_0$ or $\delta$.

The other question I am working on requires the results of the above, which again requires that I show that a function $f$ is bounded. In this problem, all I know is that $f$ is uniformly continuous over some interval $(a,b)$. Does uniform continuity imply boundedness? By using the above $ M = Max \{f(x) : x \in (a, b)\} $, this seems like it would work, but I am concerned about whether or not the function is defined at the endpoints makes a difference.

If someone could point me in the right direction, or give me some tips on how to show boundedness in a general setting like this, I would appreciate it. I have found some things using cauchy sequences, but as we have not gone over this in class I cannot use it.

EDIT: For reference, I am working from http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF

Problems 2.1.38 (p.53) and 2.2.31 (p. 72)

Comment: Uniform continuity on a bounded interval does indeed imply boundedness on that interval, if that's any help. Can you explain why?

Comment: I can see it intuitively, but I am struggling to show it. Could you fix a value of epsilon, and a value of x2?

Comment: Looking at this again, it looks very familiar, like something that was posted here in the last few days.

Comment: A thought: start by rearranging terms in the inequality with $\delta$, and think about how that combines with the other inequality to mean something.

Comment: My professor suggested that I fix epsilon as 1, and then this shows that 1 - f(x2) < f(x1) < 1 + f(x2)

but I don't understand how delta comes into play

Comment: I haven't worked this all through, but I suggest taking a sequence $(s_n)$ approaching $x_0$ from the left and proving that $(f(s_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Although it's probably a better approach, we have not covered sequences yet and thus I cannot do that.